# How to model radiation from non point sources?

Tags: radiation, geometry, radioactivity

For radioactive decay, if we assume a point source, then the number of particles at a distance $d$ away from the source scales as $1 \ /$ $d^2$. The assumption of a point source is only valid when d is relatively large.I am wondering how we would describe the number of particles at a particular point a distance d away from a source with some geometrical dimensions, say the source is a cube shielded on five sides (i.e. radiation only emitted from one face of the cube)?

Comment: Calculus: divide the source up into small regions, and treat each region as a point source. If necessary, consider the limit as the number of regions trends toward infinity and their size trends toward zero.

Comment: In many real problems people turn to things like MCNP...

Answer (score 0):

The long answer is that you have to run a neutron transport calculation - either a deterministic method like discrete ordinates method, or a Monte Carlo calculation.  The complexity of the problem depends on the exact geometry and the materials that the neutrons will be traveling through.

Fortunately, for simple problems, or where the answer does not have to be exact, there are many approximations you can make (for example, as you pointed out, if "d" is large, you can usually assume it is a point source).

Many of these approximations are typically included in books on "shielding methods".   Is there any specific scenario you had in mind?